# Using a 'superdll' within a set of DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, architecture, structure

I am redesigning the architecture of a program which interacts with hardware. Currently, it is in two parts, a `dll` and an `exe`. The `exe` handles the general process, and the `dll` handles the device drivers. Currently, the `dll` is very bloated and has loads of `if/else` statements about which driver to use.

My plan in the redesign is to separate the `dll` into a multitude of `dll`'s, one for each device driver. All of the drivers would have similar properties, so my thoughts are currently that there would be a kind of 'superclass' for all the `dll`'s, which would in itself be a `dll`.

As far as I can see, it is not possible to have inheritance across `dll`'s, having read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/815065/what-is-a-dll) article. So my question is, is it possible to have a 'superdll' and have other `dll`'s that inherit from that? Is this even a good idea?

Comment: Unless there's a *reason* to separate the library into multiple libraries I would not do this.  It just causes more headaches.

Comment: Object inheritance doesn't have anything to do with it.  A dll does not "inherit" another dll, it simply uses it.  It automagically becomes "super" when a lot of dlls use it, no help necessary.  Do google "dll hell" so you at least have some idea what can go wrong.